# How to add "\n" at the end of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I know how to do it on the string, so `"hello world"` would be `"hello world\n"`. But if I have something like `char *str = "helloworld".` and I want to add \n at the end of str, how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Comment: It will be the same. You can do `char *str = "helloworld\n"`.

Comment: You can't add anything to "helloworld". "helloworld" is always "helloworld", it can't be "helloworld\n" unless you change it to "helloworld\n".

Answer (score 12):

You can't do this.

When you use

```
char *str = "helloworld";
```

`str` points to a string that cannot be modified. It also doesn't have any extra space available beyond the characters in the literal, so you can't extend its size.

If you need a string that's the same as `str` but with an added newline, you need to make a copy first.

```
char *newstr = malloc(strlen(str) + 2);
strcpy(newstr, str);
strcat(newstr, "\n");
```

Remember to add 2 to the length: 1 byte for the newline being added, another for the trailing null.

See [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha) for more information about the differences between using

```
char str[] = "helloworld";
```

and

```
char *str = "helloworld";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared **string literals**, which cannot be modified. You will need to do something like:

```
char *str;
str = malloc (sizeof (char) * MAX_SIZE);
strcpy (str, "HelloWorld");
strcat (str, "\n");
```

or, You should use an array.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't add/concatenate more characters to the end of `str` in your code example without some form of reallocation of space.

But if I may respond to what might be the real aim of your question (you asked specifically about appending a newline and not just any text, which makes me think you are trying to format text for output), you can easily add `'\n'` alongside `str` when you send it to stdout:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

In fact, you can prepend/append whatever you like before/after `str` by altering the format string:

```
printf(">>> %s <<<\n", str);
```

`printf()` has lots of "friends", e.g. `fprintf()` for outputting to a file instead of stdout, that behave similarly.

This way, you don't need to worry about reallocating anything just to append a newline or otherwise format the text for output.

Does that help?